# Intermittent SQL Insert Error

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a system where we do a monthly job of inserting about a million  records into a table. It has been working without any errors and generally continues to do so. Strangely it seems to hit a hump at some point. This month the records up until the 13th September at 21:15:12 for only one of many similar productIDs inserted fine but then suddenly stopped inserting for just productID 37.

The code which fails is:

```
INSERT INTO tblFooBar (productID, dDate, dTime) VALUES (37,'﻿2017-09-13','21:15:12')
```

It gives this error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07' Conversion
>   failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If I remove the productID field it enters without any problem:

```
INSERT INTO tblFooBar (dDate, dTime) VALUES ('﻿2017-09-13','21:15:12')
```

Comment: Did you try with `13-09-2017`?

Comment: Could you show the table's columns data types?

Comment: Use ISO-8601 date format.

Comment: Consider parameterized queries to avoid parsing errors. If you must use string literals, use ISO 8601 unseparated date format (YYYYMMDD). Not sure what the root cause here is if it works just by removing ProduceID (trigger maybe?).

Comment: Does the productId exist?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The column datatypes are: productID = int, dDate = date, dTime = time(7)

Comment: It is worth noting that this has worked for about a million records every month this year so the formats do match up. It is the randomness of the error that has me puzzled. Why would it insert ten million times but then randomly start failing for just one productID in the middle of a month? I just checked and that product is in the table 4,240,994 times already.

Comment: I'm willing to bet good money that (per Dan) there's a trigger on `tblFooBar` that ultimately causes the error, since the logic for parsing dates and times doesn't vary with what's in the other columns.

Comment: Yes, I also considered triggers but there are no stored procedures used in the database.

Comment: Triggers and stored procedures have nothing to do with each other. You can call a sproc from a trigger, but that's it. Triggers on tables are represented separately in SSMS, or check with `select * from sys.triggers`.

Comment: Hi Jeroen. Many thanks for your reply. There are no records in sys.triggers.

Comment: Then I'm inclined to say that what we're told is happening is impossible, and you've somehow managed to simplify the problem to the point where it can't be reproduced. Specifically, I can think of no way to make SQL Server fail and issue an error with one statement and not the other if `tblFooBar` is a plain table without any triggers and the statements are issued literally with `sqlcmd` or SSMS on the same connection, regardless of the values involved. Throw in parameters, client code, `SET LANGUAGE` options or other things and it's possible, but otherwise no, barring a very implausible bug.

Comment: That's exactly why I am foxed. I have been scratching my head on this for days. To add to the simplicity tblFooBar is the only table in the database.

Comment: INSERT INTO tblFooBar (productID) VALUES (37) also inserts without error.

Comment: Any `CHECK` constraints? The final thing you can try is actually compare execution plans between the queries (Query -> Include Actual Execution Plan in Management Studio). They should both produce trivial insert plans.

Comment: There are no check constraints and 2017-09-13 worked for previous inserts.

Comment: I included the Actual Execution Plan and it only displayed for a test entry. It gave me (reading from left to right) INSERT cost 0%, CLUSTERED INDEX INSERT cost 100%, COMPUTE SCALAR cost 0%, COMPUTE SCALAR cost 0% and CONSTANT SCAN cost 0%

Comment: An update on this for anyone that is interested. I paired it down to basic principles as much as possible and have been validating the data with a convert function SELECT CONVERT(date,'2017-09-14'). When I run the native input it fails but when I overtype the 2017 in management studio in one go it executes successfully. If I overtype each number individually and try to execute it between each number it fails.

Comment: The plot thickens! When I copy a failed date that looks like '2017-09-14' from management studio into Textpad I get '?2017-09-14'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad to say I have resolved the issue. It was not really a SQL Server issue.

The problem was to do with the source dates that I was copying into the SQL statement. They had spurious ï, » and ¿ characters that a third party program had added to the dates and that I had not detected because of encoding.